# Illegal Enclosing Instance inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, class

I have this code:

```
MainFragmentActivity a = new MainFragmentActivity();
MainFragmentActivity.MasterFrag mm = a.new MasterFrag(); // a.new
MainFragmentActivity.MasterFrag.MasterTask e = mm.new MasterTask();
e.execute();
```

On the `a.new` line referenced above, it has a problem with `a`.  It says:

```
Illegal enclosing instance specification for type MainFragmentActivity.MasterFrag
```

This block of code is inside a static method inside a `Fragment` (not static) inside a `FragmentActivity`.  I am not sure how to declare this `a` var?  Making this a `static` call is not an option either...  How can I get a reference to the `MainFragmentActivity` instance?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You already created instance for `MainFragmentActivity ` and you are still asking how?

Comment: Do `new MainFragmentActivity.MasterFrag()` if you haven't already imported the classes if you're trying to make instances of enclosed classes.

Comment: @A--C Your way answered it.  the a.new came from another question I asked along time ago.  Not sure where they got that from but I thought it had worked.

Comment: You can't get there from here.  The static method exists outside of any `Fragment` or `Activity`, so you can't get a reference to the `MainFragmentActivity` - there is not necessarily going to be one.  I agree with @HeikoRupp, look at what you are trying to do and find another way.  Or, without further info on your specific case, if you make your remove the `static` modifier from the method in question, you can access the enclosing `Activity` with `getActivity()`

Comment: @KickingLettuce imagreen's explanation is pretty spot on. If the classes are `static` you use my approach since static classes don't need their enclosing parent class instance. `a.new` works for non static. [You should read the Oracle explanation on this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: @iagreen  That makes perfect sense, tried it your way and that does work better. Thanks... Again, I was taking one suggestion for another situation and misapplying it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you would get this compilation error if the inner class MasterFrag is declared to be static.  The correct way to instantiate it would then be:

```
MainFragmentActivity.MasterFrag mm = new MainFragmentActivity.MasterFrag();
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue because an inner class was defined in an interface. So that means that class must be static by default.